# How can i delete record in user table that has foreign key with profile table?

Tags: django

I have profile table :

'''

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

'''

and User table that is relate with profile .
i want to delete record from user table ,but i can not,

'''

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_user(request,user_id):
    try:
        if 'json' in request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT'):
            user_selected = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
            user_selected.refresh_from_db()
            user_selected.delete()
            return JsonResponse({'code': 100})
        else:
            return redirect('/')

    except:
        return JsonResponse({'code': 101})
```

'''
user_selected.delete() did not work!!